# proof involving divergence theorem for fluid dynamics

Tags: integration, vector-analysis, fluid-dynamics

I have been trying to derive from $(\vec{u}.\nabla)\vec{u}=-\frac{1}{\rho}\nabla P$ $*$

that $$\rho\iint_{S}(\vec{u}.\vec{n})\vec{u}dS=-\iint_Sp\vec{n}dS$$ where as usual $\vec{n}$ is a unit vector outward from $S$.

I first took the volume intergrals of both sides of $*$ which gave the following

$$\iiint_{V}(\vec{u}.\nabla)\vec{u}dV=\iiint_{V}-\frac{1}{\rho}\nabla P dV$$ now by the divergence theorem for scalars the RHS of the above equation becomes

$$\iiint_{V}(\vec{u}.\nabla)\vec{u}dV=-\frac{1}{\rho}\iint_{S}p\vec{n}dS$$, but this is where i'm stuck, i know i need to rewrite the LHS before i can arrive at the equtaion i'm aiming for i'm just unsure how to do this, i assume i will be needing to use at least two integral transforms to get my required results, any help with this would be highly appreciated.

This gives a formal proof of the statement that, in a steady incompressible flow, the total force due to hydrostatic pressure exerted on a control surface is equal to the net outward rate of momentum outflow.

Comment: As I had misreas the question,  I will answer what you were truly asking later today when I get a moment.  I apologize for the misreading.

Comment: Brilliant thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This form of the momentum equation, where the density is treated as a constant, holds for an incompressible fluid with the added condition $\nabla \cdot \mathbb{u} = 0$.

Using Cartesian components and the Einstein convention for repeated indices ($a_ib_i = \sum_ia_ib_i$), the ith component of $\mathbb{u} \cdot \nabla \mathbb{u} $ is

$$(\mathbb{u} \cdot \nabla \mathbb{u})_i = u_j \frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x_j} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}(u_iu_j) - u_i \frac{\partial u_j}{\partial x_j}.$$

For an ***incompressible fluid*** we have $\nabla \cdot \mathbb{u} = \frac{\partial u_j}{\partial x_j} = 0.$

Hence, the ith component of the integral is

$$\tag{*}\int_V (\mathbb{u} \cdot \nabla \mathbb{u})_i \, dV = \int_V \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}(u_iu_j) \, dV = \int_S u_i u_j n_j \, dS = \int_S (\mathbb{u} \cdot \mathbb{n})u_i \, dS$$

and in vector form

$$\int_V \mathbb{u} \cdot \nabla \mathbb{u} \, dV= \int_S (\mathbb{u} \cdot \mathbb{n})\mathbb{u} \, dS.$$

Note that in (*) we applied the divergence theorem in the form

$$\int_V \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j} \, dV = \int_S f n_j \, dS.$$

Comment: Brilliant , thank you this is what i was looking for, would you be able to into more detail about the last note you put?, and for$a_{i}b_{i}=\sum_{i}a_{i}b_{i}$ bit what is the index here, is it just the ith components? similarly for the $u_{i}u_{j}$ is the $u_{j}$ component just referring to the $j$th component of $u$, and the $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}$  what does this mean? is $x_{j}$ just $x,y,z$ where $j=x,y,z$ ?

Comment: I'm using $x_1, x_3, x_3$  in place of $x, y,z$.  The convention is $a_ib_i = a_1b_1 + a_2b_2 + a_3b_3$ so we don't have to clutter things up with summation symbols.  For example $\nabla \cdot \mathbb{u} = \frac{\partial u_j}{\partial x_j} = \frac{\partial u_1}{\partial x_1} + \frac{\partial u_2}{\partial x_2}+\frac{\partial u_3}{\partial x_3}$.

Comment: You already recognized that $\int_v \nabla p \, dV = \int_S p \mathbb{n} \, dS$ as a form of the divergence theorem.  This is derivable from the basic form in my note where on a component by component basis you have, for example, $\int_V \frac{\partial p}{\partial x_1} \, dV = \int_S p n_1 \, dS$.